# PHP pgsql doesnt load from command line

Tags: php, postgresql, cmd

*I saw a similar question "Loads only from the command line"*. I have a different issue and on **windows OS**. I need to test some parts of code that has connections to other HTTPS sites, and I assume my browser caches some stuff that drops an error for the output. There for, I need to test my php script with a windows command line - which isnt hard to do. How ever, on `pg_fetch_all` it drops `Call to undefined Function pg_fetch_all`.

But I assume it connects to the database using `pg_connect`, otherwise it would drop an error before hand.

Is there something I am missing? Does pg_fetch_all has some values that I missed on reading about it? Or its simply because it is not loading a plugin, etc..

- *I am using **PHP5.6***
- *Loading it with simply: **php file.php***

---

My code for SQL as requested.

```
$station_keys = pg_fetch_all(
   pg_query(
      get_connection(), "SELECT val, val2, val3, val4 FROM table_keys"));
```

Everything works fine on browser *(maybe apache's doing)*, the command line thinks it's weird.

My `php -m` prints out:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

`pdsql` is missing, it is enabled on wamp, it doesn't load when I am running command line.

Comment: Share you code with us so we can have a look. Otherwise we can only guess and i don't think it will be beneficial for you.

Comment: Not sure how will it make a situation any different, it runs on browser (That bit), the issue is the command line, not the script itself.

Comment: run `php -m` to list the loaded modules. If `pgsql` is not there, then the problem is in the php configuration used.

Comment: Also you are missing a double quote at the end.

Comment: Sorry, there was something more, but I deleted it that why it was missing ". and thanks @coladict didint know how to debug it, but like I assumed there is pgsql missing from there. Any idea how to add it, it is enabled on wamp,

Comment: Running `php -i` will tell you exactly where the CLI is looking for a `php.ini` configuration. It will also tell you a whole bunch of other stuff we don't need for this. You need to change it to load the pgsql extension. Hopefully it will come pre-compiled somewhere for you.

Comment: @coladict yep, found it, thanks alot, could you post it as an answer, so if more people search it, theill find it, and I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using [Coladict](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3841161/coladict) comment, the pgsql wasn't loading in command line, since I was using 5.6 version, from the files, not wamp, it wasn't included in my `php.ini` config file, found the `pdsql`, un commented and it works like a charm, used `php -m` to see which plugins are currently loaded, then `php -i` to see where the `php.ini` file is located.

I suggested Coladict to answer it as an answer, so other people would see it, how ever he didn't respond.